# Using a setState in a ChangeNotifier's addListener callback

Tags: flutter

In flutter, in the code below, `_controller` is a ChangeNotifier.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = Controller();
  _controller.addListener(() => setState(() {}));
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _controller.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Is this a valid way to use a ChangeNotifier? Are there any risks or memory leaks associated with this type of usage?

Every other source I refered were talking about using provider package's ChangeNotifierProvider and Consumer. I cannot use provider for some reasons in the project.

Comment: It is a valid way but the point is, it rebuilds the whole widget tree every time whenever changeNotifier fires.

Comment: So quickly creating a wrapper widget that consumes the `_controller` above and using this wrapper widget above widgets that are dependent on the `_controller` should solve the issue?

Comment: If you are using `notifyListeners` with `ChangeNotifier`, why do you need `_controller.addListener(() => setState(() {}));` because notifyListenrs internally do the same `notifier.addListener(() => setState(() {}));`

Comment: @Blasanka I'm only using a ChangeNotifer in the Widget and nothing else. How would the widget have any knowledge about this _controller? That's why I put setState in addListener.